# Property of well-formed contexts in Martin-Löf type theory

Tags: logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In Appendix A (page 426) of the IAS book *Homotopy Type Theory*, you find the following remark.

> Such judgments are sensible only for well-formed contexts, a notion captured by our third and final judgment
> $$
>   (x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2, \dotsc, x_n : A_n) \ \text{ctx}
> $$
> expressing that each $A_i$ is a type in the context $x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2, \dotsc, x_{i-1} : A_{i-1}$. In particular, therefore, if $\Gamma \vdash a : A$ and $\Gamma \ \text{ctx}$, then we know that each $A_i$ contains only the variables $x_1, \dotsc, x_{i-1}$, and that $a$ and $A$ contain only the variables $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$.

When you read the entire presentation of the type theory, it’s not hard to see that  this description does, in fact, hold  in the system. But this remark comes before the formal presentation of all the inference rules and never refers to them. Therefore, I do not see how it follows just from the meaning of a well-formed context.

Could someone please clarify this?

Comment: The formal presentation *is* referred to. The last sentence of the first paragraph of that section is: "These judgments are inductively defined by a set of inference rules described in Appendix A.2." The "third and final judgment" is referring to this presentation. This remark is not the formal definition of a well-formed context. It is just an informal explanation of one of the judgements that will be defined. It's much easier to understand a formal presentation if you know what informal idea it is intended to capture.

Comment: Can you clarify what "description" or "remark" you are referring to?  The text you quoted contains two sentences, each with several phrases, and I can't guess exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st presentation, the referred inference rule is in A.1.1 (introduction of a new variable to define a new context).
For the 2nd presentation, the referred inference rules are in A.2.1 (ctx-EMP, ctx-EXT).